# connection refused error when pushing lfs files

Tags: gitlab, git-lfs

I tracked some of my files with git lfs, but pushing it to remote failed with following message:

```
batch response: Post https://my_remote_repository/my_project.git/info/lfs/objects/batch: dial tcp (ip address):443: connect: connection refused
Uploading LFS objects:   0% (0/7), 0 B | 0 B/s, done.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://my_remote_repository/my_project.git'
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

That seems an issue on the remote side (the "my_remote_repository" hosting server)

As seen in "[Git LFS fails with error: failed to push some refs to](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/git-lfs-fails-with-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to-802591026.html)"

> ### Cause #1:
>
> This indicates the repository does not have LFS enabled. A user with REPO_ADMIN permissions is able to enable LFS support.
>
> ### Cause #2:
>
> When pushing large files through a reverse proxy to Bitbucket server, ngnix has been found guilty of this issue due 2 specific configurations that need to be tweaked for it.

You might not be using BitBucket, but the HTTPS listener on your remote side might be rejecting a file pushed because of its size.

Check also if this help, [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57914197/6309):

```
git config --global lfs.contenttype 0
```