# LFS:Put <wrong URL>

Tags: git, gitlab, git-lfs

I am new in GitLab so the question may be naïve. I am trying to push LFS object from local branch to remote. The GitLab server is configured in network computer (url for repository: http://blaws.eng.mm.edu:8080/bhossain/gitlab_lfs_test). I can clone, add and remove files in the repository using git bash. However, when I am trying to push (`git push origin main` ) LFS object it pops up following error:

```
LFS: Put "http://GitLab/bhossain/gitlab_lfs_test.git/gitlab-lfs/objects/4f7e2ccb2866ec5041993c9cf2a952bbed69647b115d0f74da7ce8f4bef82f05/815585330": dial tcp: lookup GitLab: no such host
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://blaws.eng.mm.edu:8080/bhossain/gitlab_lfs_test'
```

The commands used for tracking large files (a JPG image) are exactly same in [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/lfs/).

The output of `git lfs env` is:

```
git-lfs/3.3.0 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.19.3; git 77deabdf)
git version 2.40.0.windows.1

Endpointhttp://blaws.eng.mm.edu:8080/bhossain/gitlab_lfs_test.git/info/lfs (auth=basic)
LocalWorkingDir=D:\gitlab\gitlab_lfs_test
LocalGitDir=D:\gitlab\gitlab_lfs_test\.git
LocalGitStorageDir=D:\gitlab\gitlab_lfs_test\.git
LocalMediaDir=D:\gitlab\gitlab_lfs_test\.git\lfs\objects
LocalReferenceDirs=
TempDir=D:\gitlab\gitlab_lfs_test\.git\lfs\tmp
ConcurrentTransfers=8
TusTransfers=false
BasicTransfersOnly=false
SkipDownloadErrors=false
FetchRecentAlways=false
FetchRecentRefsDays=7
FetchRecentCommitsDays=0
FetchRecentRefsIncludeRemotes=true
PruneOffsetDays=3
PruneVerifyRemoteAlways=false
PruneRemoteName=origin
LfsStorageDir=D:\gitlab\gitlab_lfs_test\.git\lfs
AccessDownload=basic
AccessUpload=basic
DownloadTransfers=basic,lfs-standalone-file,ssh
UploadTransfers=basic,lfs-standalone-file,ssh
GIT_EXEC_PATH=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
```

According to [here](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/4172), the link (`http://GitLab/bhossain/gitlab_lfs_test.git/gitlab-lfs/objects/....`) is generated by GitLab server. I am guessing that the local host can not reach the URL (**dial tcp: lookup GitLab: no such host**). The [official guideline](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html#configuring-the-external-url-for-gitlab) suggest to add `external_url` in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` and reconfigure GitLab with `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`.

This is different from this [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51724041/git-lfs-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to) [post2](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4794) (as server installed in NAS drive).

Does adding `external_url "http://blaws.eng.mm.edu:8080"` would solve the problem? Is there any way to configure this from GitLab web interface? Could someone help me to explain how to get rid of this issue?